# возврат вектора из функции c++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, c++14

Есть такая функция:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> unique(vector<int> *v)
{
    vector<int> unique_elements = {};
    sort((*v).begin(), (*v).end());
    unique_elements.push_back((*v)[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < (*v).size(); i++)
    {
        if((*v)[i] != (*v)[i - 1])
        {
            unique_elements.push_back((*v)[i]);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Что надо написать в return функции и что надо написать в функцию main, чтобы вывести вектор? И верно ли вообще, что надо выводить именно вектор, а не указатель на него например? А если надо выводить указатель, то в каких случаях вообще нужно выводить из функции указатель, а в каких сам вектор? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `return unique_elements;` В `main` присвойте его соответствующей переменной и выводите обычным циклом.

Comment: Вот указатель в качестве аргумента функции тут точно не нужен.

Comment: Указатель то да, а вот константная ссылка не помешала бы.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков но в чем вообще будет различие между вектором, указателем на вектор и ссылкой на вектор в качестве аргумента функции? я просто видел примеры разные и, как правило, если в аргументах функции будут именно отдельные переменные ```int a```, например, то функции передают указатель на эту переменную, поскольку, если передать саму переменную или ссылку на эту переменную, то передается именно копия переменной и изменения произойдут с копией, а не с элементом. Но я не понимаю, почему если аргументов функции служит массив или вектор, то передают именно ссылку? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @prostak, советую для каждого вашего вопроса создать отдельный вопрос. Мало кому охота написать целую статью, чтобы отвечать вам. У вас несколько вопросов, и, кстати, в учебниках для каждого из этих вопросах выделены целые главы, потому что ситуации бывают очень разные

Comment: @prostak при передаче по ссылке не создаётся копия.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков почему тогда, например, при передаче переменной или массива в качестве аргумента функции используют указатель, а не ссылку?

Comment: @prostak где? когда? кто? легаси?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков ну я видел, что часто при передаче массива в качестве аргумента функции используют указатель. Но почему указатель, а не ссылку?

Comment: @prostak сишный массив и C++ вектор это немного разные вещи.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков ну я имею ввиду в общем. с векторами то же самое. я видел коды, где в качестве аргумента функции передается указатель на вектор и где в качестве аргумента передается ссылка на вектор. но в чем разница я не понял. я не понял, когда лучше использовать для тех же векторов указатель, а когда ссылку.

Comment: @prostak, всегда ссылку.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всё зависит от задачи.

```
vector<int> unique_elements = {};
..
неправильно !
return & unique_elements ;
```

Возвращать указатель локального объекта неправильно, в векторе будет вызван деструктор и указатель может указывать на другую переменную, что приведёт неопределённому поведению.

---

```
vector<int> & unique(vector<int> *v) {
  ..
  vector<int> & unique_elementsp = * new vector<int> ;
  return unique_elementsp ; }

int main (){
  ..
  vector<int> v ;
  vector<int> & unique_elements = unique(&v) ;
  ..
  delete & unique_elements ;
  .. }
```

указатель или ссылку можно вернуть, если вы создали объект в куче.

---

```
vector<int> unique(vector<int> *v) {
  ..
  return unique_elements ; }

int main (){
  ..
  vector<int> v ;
  vector<int> unique_elements = unique(&v) ;
  .. }
```

можно вернуть по значению, но может быть создана лишняя копия элементов вектора. Если оптимизатор обленится.

---

```
vector<int> unique(vector<int> *v)
..
return std :: move ( unique_elements  ) ;
```

это самый экономный способ, функция вернёт созданный вектор в функции не трогая, и он будет находиться временно в стеке.

Если вектор нужен временно, то возвращайте по значению, а если будет работать долго, то создавайте в куче (с **new**) и возвращайте ссылкой.

Не забывать надо про освобождение памяти. Временные объекты удаляются автоматически, а созданные вручную с помощью `new vector<int>` нужно удалить вручную используя `delete & unique_elements ;` когда этот вектор уже не нужен.

Comment: Ну а правило "Обязательное избавление от копирования"? Зачем вообще  std :: move  тут понадобилось? Он и так не будет копироваться.

Comment: А вот так можно:
static vector<int> unique_elements = {};
return & unique_elements ;

Comment: Это привычка, когда в стандарте не было обязательной оптимизации. @AR Hovsepyan

Comment: vector<int> & unique_elementsp = * new vector<int> ;
return unique_elementsp ;
Этож жесть полная, память просто потечёт.

Comment: Ваши советы про `static` могут перестать работать, если вызвать одновременно функцию на три аргумента например. А возвращать ссылку можно, посмотите внимательно возвращаемый тип. @Никита Самоуков

Comment: "Если вектор нужен временно, то возвращайте по значению, а если будет работать долго, то создавайте в куче (с new) и возвращайте ссылкой." вектор будет находится в стеке только если ооочень постараться, наюзать stackalloc и кастомный аллокатор.

Comment: @AlexGlebe да хоть 33 аргумента, на статик это никак не повлияет. Вернуть то ссылку можно вот только выражение auto vec = unique(...); неожиданно вызовет утечку памяти. Даже в махровом легаси я не встречал возвращения нового элемента через ссылку.

Comment: `vector<int> & unique_elementsp = * new vector<int> ;` работа с указателями или ссылками это дело вкуса. "На вкус и цвет.." @НикитаСамоуков

Comment: @AlexGlebe это дело не вкуса, а здравого смысла. Если вас устраивают постоянные утечки, то это ваше дело.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать:

```
vector<int> unique(vector<int> &v)
{
    vector<int> unique_elements = {};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    unique_elements.push_back(v[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v[i] != v[i - 1])
        {
            unique_elements.push_back(v[i]);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    return unique_elements;
}
```

Но эта функция изменяет исходные данные, так как они передаются по ссылке.

Передавать же вектор в функцию можно разными способами.

По значению, тогда будет создана новая копия вектора:

```
vector<int> unique(vector<int> v)
```

По ссылке, тогда это будет обращение к тому же вектору:

```
vector<int> unique(vector<int> &v)
```

По константной ссылке, тогда это будет обращение к тому же вектору(но его будет нельзя изменять(хотя вообще если очень хочется, то все равно можно если использовать reinterpret или C cast)):

```
vector<int> unique(const vector<int> &v)
```

По указателю, тогда это будет обращение к тому же вектору(но при таком способе предполагается, что может бытm передан и nullptr):

```
vector<int> unique(vector<int> *v)
```

Comment: вопрос был как выводить вектор, а не как принимать..